# using IOS camera, got <wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003>

Tags: ios, camera, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController to let my user take a photo or choose a photo from the photoAblum.

Problem is that,

it seems OK to go to the photoAlbum,

but about 8 out of 10 times I go to the camera,

the gdb throws this warnig (or even an error?):

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

here is my code to initialize a UIImagePickerController

```
- (IBAction)fromCameraButtonTapped {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
```

the method that go the the photo ablum is almost the same as this one, except the sourceType.

What's more, it is also ok when I choose a photo back from the album,

but it often throws the same warning when I choose a new-token photo from the camera.

And once my app even crashed with a following memory warning after this strange warning.

So I thinks it is neccessary to get it over.

Anybody know what I should do?

THanks a lot!

Comment: FWIW, I get `wait_fences` occasionally on other controllers like the mail and sms composition controllers. There was a post on the Apple developer forums by an Apple employee saying "this is our problem; ignore it." That said, I've never had any failures because of it. If you're hitting the same issue as I have, your crash would have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this,

my app crashes because after a memory warning,

I set some of my very important properties in viewDidUnload, so after I touch some button or do some action, it crashes,

but I still got that strange warning.

Anyway My app works fine in the view.